# Nginx Rewrite offers me the url for download

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i'm a bit new to NGINX, and i got a issue with my rewrite rule.
My original htacess was been

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ //yourls-loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So i made this from it

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/.*$ //yourls-loader.php last; break;
}
```

The result of this is sadly that he is not excuting the PHP, he is delivering it as pure Text (i removed the standard oct). Does somebody have a idea how to fix this?

Comment: do you have proxy pass directive?

Comment: Nope, but i'm behind a load Balancer. Currently all i use this http://pastebin.com/pqswu6Ah and in the Nginx Config the Real IP directive

Comment: Add your own answer and mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I fixed this with ths simple solution in the directive

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /yourls-loader.php;
```